# Как в программе сделать другую программу?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Доброго времени суток. Начну с предыстории.

Написал я программу для сбора информации (какой именно - не суть важно), после сбора, программа загружает на полученные данные в мою БД. Что бы не запускать это с консоли, я через pyinstaller сделал красивый `ехе` файл и запускаю программу через нее.

Со временем, мне понадобилось немного расширить функционал программы, соответственно отредактировал код, сгенерировал новый `exe` все хорошо, все работает.

Но тут возникла идея, а не написать бы программу-конструктор, с использованием графического интерфейса, которая бы удаляла/добавляла функционал а после создавала мне `exe` файл.

Создать GUI интерфейс и прописать нужный код не составит труда (по крайней мере в моей голове теоретически это работает :) ), вопрос состоит только в том, как превращать исходники в `exe` файл, как использовать `pyinstaller` в таком случае?

Т.е. простыми словами `Prog1.exe` (конструктор) создает `Prog2.exe` (выходной файл)

Буду рад любым ответам, возможно вы подадите другую, более интересую идею как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Через `subprocess.run` запустить `pyinstaller`?

Comment: Можно просто поставлять "скомпилированное" в exe ядро программы + отдельные модули в виде файлов py, которые можно загружать и запускать с помощью `exec`.

Comment: делайте один exe, который при работе использует конфигурационный файл. А в "конфиг" добавляйте действий и задач сколько захотите.